# Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined ao tentar colocar validator required

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando colocar um validator de required em um campo, porém estou recebendo:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Tentei algo como:

```
<form [formGroup]="variacaoForm">
```

Minha função que cria esse form group:

```
this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

  variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

});

createFormGroup(produto?: any, indice?: number): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      sku: new FormControl('', [Validators.required
      ]),
    });
  }
```

Aqui eu tento mostrar com hasError uma mensagem de campo obrigatório:

```
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 colunasVariacao margemcoluna">
    <label class="colorLabel" for="sku{{i}}">SKU *</label>
    <input name="sku{{i}}" required formControlName="sku" type="text" class="form-control">

    <p *ngIf="sku.hasError('required')" class="primary-color">Campo obrigatório</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: Já tentou `sku?.hasError('required')"`

Answer (score 0):

esse erro ocorre pq o objeto sku não e do tipo FormControl. Vc pode tentar acessar o objeto sku: variacaoForm.controls.variacoes.controls[i].controls.sku.hasError('required')